# dual booting xp and windows 7

Tags: multi-boot

I have a c drive and a d drive...the only thing on my d drive is My Documents...can I move this folder and all of its contents to my c drive and format the d drive so I can install Windows 7 on it and dual boot xp from c and windows 7 from d drive?

Comment: Are these separate drives or partitions on the same drive?  Does D have enough space to install Win7?

Comment: This one hard drive that is partitioned into c and d. The whole drive is 750 gb divided evenly between c and d. Please respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the default location of the My Documents folder, follow these steps:

- Double-click My Computer.
- Right-click My Documents and choose Properties.
- Click the Target tab. In the Target box, do one of the following:
- (1) Type the path to the folder location that you want, and then click OK . For example, D:\My Stuff. If the folder does not exist, the Create Message dialog box is displayed. Click Yes to create the folder, and then click OK.
- (2) Or, Click Move , click the folder in which to store your documents, and then click OK twice. If you need to create a new folder, click Make New Folder. Type a name for the folder, and then click OK twice. In the Move Documents box, click Yes to move your documents to the new location, or click No to leave your documents in the original location.

[image]

Comment: This is the first thing I did when I dualbooted. Amazing how much crap I keep My Documents. 

IIRC, you may run into issues accessing the My Documents from both Win 7 and Win XP as the Win 7 premissions overwrite the Win XP permissions. There's a way around it, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Just make sure you copy/backup everything on D first, then you can do whatever you want with it. The Windows bootloader should ask you what OS you want to use at boot time.